# Why does this jquery each() loop doesn't operate on unique classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

I'm trying to make a jquery function work on classes with a unique identifier..
But it seems like it isn't adding the var to the element... How do I do this

My code is this...

```js
    var x = 1;
    $('.newest_posts').each(function() {

      $('.showFull' + x).on('click', function(e) {
        $('.newest_small' + x).hide(); // hide image preview on delete click
        $('.newest_full' + x).show(); // hide image delete link on click
        e.preventDefault();
      });

      x = x + 1;
    });
```

Not very well versed in jquery but i'm stumbled because I have this code which works for hiding them first

```js
    var i = 1;
    $('.newest_posts').each(function() {

      $('.newest_full' + i).hide();

      i = i + 1;
    });
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Well the html i a big foreach loop, think it's to much to copy here, but basically im pulling post from a database....

And I want to have two different styled DIVS, where one is hidden and one is visible and then use the handler to show/hide them...

Im giving the divs unique identifier adding by a $count php variable

So something like:

<div class ="show_small1"></div>
<div class ="show_full1"></div>

<div class ="show_small2"></div>
<div class ="show_full2"></div>

Etc.

Answer (score 2):

You have to ask the question: what does `x` equal *when the click handler is called*? It will not be equal to the `x` value when you registered the handler, but be equal to the value of `x` after the loop has completed.

Assuming nothing else modified it, it will be equal to `$(.newestPosts).length() + 2`.

Here is the quick fix for the problem:

```
var x = 1;
$('.newest_posts').each(function() {
  var xCopy = x;
  $('.showFull' + xCopy).on('click', function(e) {
    $('.newest_small' + xCopy).hide(); // hide image preview on delete click
    $('.newest_full' + xCopy).show(); // hide image delete link on click
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  x = x + 1;
});
```

It creates a new variable inside the scope of the handling function.

An even better fix is to dispense with the outer `x` and use the first parameter of the `each` handler, which will be the index.

```
$('.newest_posts').each(function(index) {
  var x = index + 1;
  $('.showFull' + x).on('click', function(e) {
    $('.newest_small' + x).hide(); // hide image preview on delete click
    $('.newest_full' + x).show(); // hide image delete link on click
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: Okay, thx alot...
Not so much into jquery yet.... But is index a default used index for a each() loop?

Comment: @MichaelBragt - Not sure I understand your question. `index` will be the zero based index of the iteration:it will be 0 for the first item, 1 for the second, 2 for the third and so on. http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

You must first understand that javascript is asynchronous, and that code doesn't run the way you'd expect it to run in a synchronous programming language.

The each loop runs when the page loads, incrementing the x variable, whereas the function you passed as a parameter to the 'click' event only runs when the actual element is clicked on the page. At that point, the value of your x is going to be the same as the number of posts that you have.

You could do it like this:

```
var x = 1;
$('.newest_posts').each(function() {

  $('.showFull' + x).on('click', function(e) {
    var thisElementsIndex = $(this).attr("class").split(' ').filter(function(el){
       return el.indexOf('showFull') != -1
    })[0].replace('showFull', '');
    $('.newest_small' + thisElementsIndex ).hide(); // hide image preview on delete click
    $('.newest_full' + thisElementsIndex ).show(); // hide image delete link on click
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  x = x + 1;
});
```

What happens here is, the 'each' iteration using the x variable makes sure that all of your classes trigger that callback when you click on them. In the callback, you retrieve the value for x from the class name and pass it to the hide/show selectors.

Comment: Ahh okay, so my function to hide all the divs works because is not for a handler? but actually to hide them 'while' the HTML is generated?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `data()` method to store its index in order to use it inside the element's onclick function:

```
var x = 1;
$('.newest_posts').each(function() {

  $('.showFull' + x).data('index', x);
  $('.showFull' + x).on('click', function(e) {
    var index = $(this).data('index');
    $('.newest_small' + index).hide(); // hide image preview on delete click
    $('.newest_full' + index).show(); // hide image delete link on click
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  x = x + 1;
});
```

This have the advantage that maps each iteration index to its corresponding element, allowing other functions to benefit from it; also you don't have to care about the value of x, whose scope is out of the function.